# How to export data to .psv file in mysql with table headers?

Tags: mysql

i want to export my table data into a .psv file but i didn't get the column names in the resultant file. MY query is like

```
SELECT id,site,zip,'08/14/2017' as date,Imagelink,price,price_mult,Eprice,Eindicator,altprice,Altpricemult,Ealtprice,AltIndicator,pack,unit,uom,'' as size,product_id,upc,asin,category,description,note,rating,'' as valid,pageimage,aisle,orig_upc,job_number,sale_enddate INTO OUTFILE 'c:\\file_name.psv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
from table_name
```

is anyone have any idea how can i do it? because i have a large amount of data (almost 900000 rows and 50 columns in a table) which take too much time when i use union clause in this query to insert column names.

Comment: but it take too much time( almost 2 to 3 hours ) to execute my query because there is around 30 columns and table have almost 900000 rows.

Comment: any other way instead of using union or union all clause?